# Is it possible to check if a request was made from IMG tag?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, view, request-headers

I have an ActionResult at `http://example/image.png`

Is there a way to determine if the URL is being requested from

```
<img src="http://example/image.png" />
```

Or was opened from

```
<a href="http://example/image.png" target="_blank" />
```

?

So I can control the result with...

```
public ActionResult ViewPhoto()
{
    if (<img src />)
    {
        return File();
    }
    else
    {
        return View();
    }
}
```

Comment: If you want a different result, then perhaps you should use different images? Doing otherwise will produce unmaintainable code (who, looking at your code years later, would have any idea you'd done such a strange thing)?

Comment: @BrunoLM check server **accept** header like this : [https://64.media.tumblr.com/694a5b96de1c953891e9eb4397845f74/c51e2fb934ed5095-f5/s540x810/c69c182a904fc73b9fae51b0eafd845710e970e0.gifv](https://64.media.tumblr.com/694a5b96de1c953891e9eb4397845f74/c51e2fb934ed5095-f5/s540x810/c69c182a904fc73b9fae51b0eafd845710e970e0.gifv)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No there is no way with the format in the question to know. If you own the site that the link is coming from then I recommend you append something on the query string to help your server side processing.

Answer (score 2):

You can check if `Request.Headers["Accept"]` does not contain the string `"html"`.

Answer (score 0):

If this is a web page, I think that you can try out with `Request.UrlReferrer`, or `ServerVariables["HTTP_REFERER"]` depending on your needs. The former returns a URI object, the latter returns string.

But this is provided that you have gone to the ActionResult ViewPhoto() method

Comment: I get the same referer from `<a target="_blank" ...`, that's actually why I posted this example...

Comment: oic, missed that out, in that case, how do you handle ur image? Dealing with web, I believe u understand querystring. As in 'image.png&location=blank' for example. So in your viewPhoto method, u get the querystring for location. Try if it helps

Answer (score 0):

You could put a GET param on the image, like

```
<img src="http://example/image.png?x=view" />
```

and

```
<a href="http://example/image.png?x=file" target="_blank" />
```

Would that work for you?

Comment: I won't have control on the code. An user can change/remove the parameters.